# mostrar registro aunque no tenga informacion en inner join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un proceso en SQl donde hago un inner join de una tabla A a una tabla B, ligandolos a traves de una columna en comun llamada serie, esto se hace digamos que de forma masiva ya que no tengo una condicion en la union de las tablas, el detalle que no he podido resolver es como hacer para que en dado caso de que en un registro no haya coincidencia colocar unicamente mostrar unicamente el valor del campo serie ya que actualmente me omite esos registros que no coinciden pero quiero que si aparesca la serie aunque no tengan información, mi codigo sql es:

```html
declare @query nvarchar(max)
--set @variable='123'
IF not Exists (select * from [Serie] A 
INNER JOIN [Inventario] B ON A.InventarioClave = B.InventarioClave 
INNER JOIN [catEstatus] C ON B.EstatusInv = C.catEstatusClave 
INNER JOIN [Articulo] D ON B.ArticuloClave = D.ArticuloClave 
INNER JOIN [Entidad] E ON B.EntidadClave = E.EntidadClave 
INNER JOIN Apoyo.dbo.RegistrosReporteAlmacen F ON A.Valor = F.CDSN)
--WHERE A.Valor=@variable)
begin
select @variable AS SERIE,'NO UBICADO' AS NOMBRE,'NO UBICADO' AS UBICACION,'NO UBICADO' AS ESTATUS
end
else
begin
select  A.Valor AS SERIE,D.NOMBRE,E.NOMBRE AS UBICACION,C.NOMBRE AS ESTATUS  from [Serie] A 
INNER JOIN [Inventario] B ON A.InventarioClave = B.InventarioClave 
INNER JOIN [catEstatus] C ON B.EstatusInv = C.catEstatusClave 
INNER JOIN [Articulo] D ON B.ArticuloClave = D.ArticuloClave 
INNER JOIN [Entidad] E ON B.EntidadClave = E.EntidadClave 
INNER JOIN Apoyo.dbo.RegistrosReporteAlmacen F ON A.Valor = F.CDSN
--WHERE A.Valor=@variable
end
```

Si lo hago de forma individual si funciona pero ya de forma masiva no se como se realizaria, quiza con un ciclo por eso busco su ayuda

Comment: Prueba con `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Haz probado usar el LEFT JOIN en vez de INNER?

Comment: Si he probado con left pero me trae mucho mas registros que los que tengo en mi tabla A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero obtuve los registros nulos en una query y en otra query obtuve los registros coincidentes de las 2 tablas, posteriormente los uni con UNION ALL y asi complete el numero de registros que estaba buscando

```html
select F.CDSN AS SERIE1,D.NOMBRE,E.NOMBRE AS UBICACION,C.NOMBRE AS ESTATUS  from [Serie] A  
LEFT JOIN [Inventario] B ON A.InventarioClave = B.InventarioClave 
LEFT JOIN [catEstatus] C ON B.EstatusInv = C.catEstatusClave 
LEFT JOIN [Articulo] D ON B.ArticuloClave = D.ArticuloClave 
LEFT JOIN [Entidad] E ON B.EntidadClave = E.EntidadClave 
right JOIN Apoyo.dbo.RegistrosReporteAlmacen F   ON F.CDSN =  A.Valor
WHERE A.Valor is null
UNION ALL
select F.CDSN AS SERIE1,D.NOMBRE,E.NOMBRE AS UBICACION,C.NOMBRE AS ESTATUS from [Serie] A 
INNER JOIN [Inventario] B ON A.InventarioClave = B.InventarioClave 
INNER JOIN [catEstatus] C ON B.EstatusInv = C.catEstatusClave 
INNER JOIN [Articulo] D ON B.ArticuloClave = D.ArticuloClave 
INNER JOIN [Entidad] E ON B.EntidadClave = E.EntidadClave 
INNER JOIN Apoyo.dbo.RegistrosReporteAlmacen F ON A.Valor = F.CDSN
```